# Excel VBA Exit For does not work inside If block

Tags: vba, excel, loops

```
Dim valCheck As Variant

For i = 0 To row1
    For j = 0 To col1
        MsgBox ("started" & i)
        valCheck = Range("A1").Offset(i, j).Value
        MsgBox (valCheck)
        If valCheck = "Details" Then
            MsgBox ("found")
            ActiveCell = Range("A1").Offset(i + 1, j)
            Exit For
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: You can't use 2 x `Exit For` like this, it will only use the first one, and exit the `For j` loop. what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I want to loop through a row1 X col1 matrix until i find desired word="Details" and select the column in which it is present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as the first Exit For executes, it bypasses the second. You need to place the second Exit For outside the inner loop.

```
Dim valCheck As Variant

For i = 0 To row1
    For j = 0 To col1
        MsgBox ("started" & i)
        valCheck = Range("A1").Offset(i, j).Value
        MsgBox (valCheck)
        If valCheck = "Details" Then
            MsgBox ("found")
            ActiveCell = Range("A1").Offset(i + 1, j)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
    If valCheck = "Details" Then Exit For
Next i
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to have 2 `For` loops and `Exit For`, you can simply use the `Find` function instead.

```
Dim FindRng As Range

Set FindRng = Cells.Find("Details")
If Not FindRng Is Nothing Then ' Find was successful
    FindRng.Select ' <-- not sure what you want to do after you find the cell with "Details" ?
Else ' Find failed
    MsgBox "Unable to find 'details'", vbCritical
End If
```